# How to start activity twice with different layout and not keep it in activity back stack in Android

Tags: android, back-stack, activity-stack

I have activities flow:

```
+--+   +--+   +----+
|A1|-->|A2|-->|Home|
+--+   +--+   +----+
```

BACK button in A1 and Home should close the app. So I call `finish()` on A1 when A2 is started and also on A2 when Home is started (thanks to that A1 and A2 are never kept on back stack).

However, BACK button in A2 should lead to A1 so I override in A2 (A1 is already finished as stated above so I have to start it again)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Now, it's possible to start again with button in Home the sequence

```
Home (button pressed)->A1->A2->(return to Home)
```

In this case (i.e. when A1->A2 is started after Home) layout of A1 should be a little bit different.

Comment: If i understand your question correct then you want to jump between the activities with back button. override  onBackPressed in all the activities and use your same code Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), A1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

Comment: you can instead of call finish,in which activity that you want to close the program ,clear stack before perform back click.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the UP action, instead of the BACK action.
Read this first to understand the difference http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Also, this is how you could skip A2, from Home:

Manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.yourpackage.A1">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.yourpackage.A2"  
    android:parentActivityName="com.yourpackage.A1" >

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.yourpackage.A1"/>
</activity>

<activity
    android:name="com.yourpackage.Home"  
    android:parentActivityName="com.yourpackage.A1" >

    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
    <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.yourpackage.A1"/>
</activity>
```

In A2 and in Home:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Activate the UP navigation in the actionbar
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    //Other stuff

}


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            case android.R.id.home:
                homeUpAction();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void homeUpAction() {
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
        if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
            // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new
            // task when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
            TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                    // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                    .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                            // Navigate up to the closest parent
                    .startActivities();
        } else {
            // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply navigate
            // up to the logical parent activity.
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        }
    }
```